# Can't install missing drivers on my laptop

Tags: laptop, drivers

I formatted my computer from windows 10 to windows 7. Now the ethernet cable,wifi and usb ports are not recognized. If I go in device manager they all have a yellow !. What alternative do I have to get the drivers? I dont have a CD/DVD reader on the laptop.

Comment: USB ports should be recognized by your windows 7 after installation, try a usb stick on all ports and check which one is working fine.

Comment: none are working

Comment: How did you format it?

Comment: I'd be tempted to boot off the USB stick and attempt a fresh install of Windows 10 again. It's odd that USB isn't recognised and without that, Ethernet or wi-fi working you're pretty much stuffed.

Comment: I formatted it with a bootable usb, but after the formatting, it doesnt recognize USB ports anymore. Now I have internet working but USB still aren't working. I guess I'll have to install win10 again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put another OS on a USB drive, e.g. [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Go to BIOS/UEFI, enable legacy boot, and change boot order and other settings to allow booting from USB. Almost *all* systems can be set to boot from a USB drive, even though the OS does not recognize it.

Use the browser on the USB drive to download needed drivers.

Mount the HDD in the PC.

Copy drivers to a convenient folder on the HDD.

Reboot and install them.

BTW, you might prefer an alternate OS, which can be tested from the USB without need to install it.

Comment: I ended up putting my files on a bootable USB, then transfered them with the command prompt from system restore accessed through the boot manager or something

Answer (score 1):

On another computer, download all the drivers needed for your laptop.
Remove your laptop's internal hard disk and connect it to the other computer externally by using an HDD enclosure (You can buy it from any PC shop) and copy the drivers to it then return it back to its original place and install the drivers normally.

Comment: that would work, I found that you can transfer files from a bootable usb so I did that it was faster